# How to convert XBOX 360 save to PC save?

Tags: xbox-360, windows-10, rise-of-the-tomb-raider

The title of the question suggests it. It's specifically for the Rise of the Tomb Raider, and I am using the PC version. I want to use my Xbox 360 (from my brother's Xbox 360 actually but I played the game on that first) save. Now because I invested a lot of time on Survival mode, and now I would not be able to play on his Xbox 360, so I want to transfer my save. The problem is that I would be playing this game at my home on PC, so how would I get that save from the Xbox 360?

Comment: This question is tagged as Xbox 360 but Rise of the Tomb Raider was released for Xbox One/PS4 and PC?

Answer (score 4):

Just from some light research around Google, this seems to be impossible to do, at least for Rise of the Tomb Raider. The 360 likely has a proprietary format that it saves in for that console, which is different than how the game would save on a PC.

[This post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/391220/discussions/0/352788917754762655/) on the Steam forums references the Xbox One version, which would likely be more in line with how a PC saves games, yet it's still not a likely possibility.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that might work is a program called [Modio](http://modio.en.lo4d.com/). I used it about a year ago to transfer my Skyrim save from my Xbox 360 to my PC.

If I remember correctly, you will need an empty flash drive because you will need to convert at least part of its storage into the format the Xbox 360 uses. You use that drive to grab your file off the Xbox's storage and then plug it into your computer and find the files with Modio for use on Windows.

Whether or not this will work for Rise of the Tomb Raider, I can't say for sure but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: I want to say that Skyrim is a special case, because I've seen a manual conversion process before.

Comment: True, skyrim is a special case, but ROTR saves differently on Xbox 360 than PC, as the savegame01.dat is a much larger file than save1.dat.